# Cannot get LOB data from SQL Server transaction logs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, transaction-log, database-internals

I am trying to extract all information (*Insert*, *Update* and *Delete* Operations) from the transaction log file of SQL Server manually. For this work, I am using the undocumented functions `fn_dblog` and `fn_dump_dblog` for SQL Server.

There are 3 allocation units (`sys.allocation_units`) in transaction log file Partition (`sys.partitions`).

1. `IN_ROW_DATA`
2. `ROW_OVERFLOW_DATA`
3. `LOB_DATA`

In all of these allocation units, we found a `RowLogContents0` column that contains the **data of that row** in hexadecimal format. I can get real data from the `RowLogContents0` column, when I have an `IN_ROW_DATA` allocation unit type in my table. But when I have `ROW_OVERFLOW_DATA` or `LOB_DATA` allocation unit type in my table then I am unable to get data from `RowLogContents0` column.

Does anyone know how I can get data using `RowLogContents0` column which is stored in `ROW_OVERFLOW_DATA` and `LOB_DATA` allocation unit type?

I am following these links to get inserted and updated data from logs:

- [This one](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Transaction+Log/71415/) for inserted record
- [This one](https://raresql.com/2012/02/01/how-to-recover-modified-records-from-sql-server-part-1/) for modified record

Now I am able to get these records and queries. But facing problem when trying to get LOB records as describe above.

**Note :** I don't want to use any third party tool to do this, because I am trying to make a third party tool for my program. Right now we are only focusing on SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 2):

If you absolutely want to do this then I would advise you use a 3rd party product that does this for you. These ***undocumented*** functions are just that, along with the log structure.

> I can get real data from `RowLogContents0` column when I have `IN_ROW_DATA` allocation unit type in my table.

Each type of log record *may* have its own way of storing the data and could change between operations. There *may* be additional considerations for each record type as well... for example, in-memory records will not be properly processed using your above methods. There also may be additional considerations between **versions** of SQL Server.

> Note : I don't want to use any third party tool to do this, because I am trying to make a third party tool for my program.

Then I wish you the best in your trial and error to figure out what works and what doesn't work for each specific type of interaction of DML, row store, etc.

The only other recourse you may have is talking with Microsoft if you're a partner and attempting to obtain help with this endeavor.

**Disclaimer**: I work for Microsoft.